# Программа для составления блок-схемы

Tags: c++, блок-схема, поиск-программ

Посоветуйте, какой программой можно сделать блок-схему к коду.

Comment: Dia, Draw из OpenOffice или Visio из Microsoft Office.

Comment: ИМХО блок-схемы вообще не очень приспособлены, чтобы с помощью них программы описывать:)

Comment: попробуйте FCEditor 1.6  хотя я примера кода не видел, да  и вопрос был задан в 2012 году. Ну а вдруг кому-то пригодится мой комментарий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не очень большая и не сильно сложная, то можно в бесплатном варианте [lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com/), там есть экспорт и Visio; хотя, код глянул, наверное, сложновато там получится...

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [ConceptDraw PRO](http://conceptdraw.com/products/drawing-tool) в нем можно и UML и Блок-схемы сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что существуют программы, способные автоматически нарисовать блок-схему. UML-диаграммы, типа взаимодействия между классами -- возможно, а блок-схему по советстким стандартам -- очень маловероятно.

А если рисовать самому -- любой векторный редактор

Comment: Не согласен! Наверняка существуют подобные программы, вопрос только в иx качестве. Помню, даже в школе был такой учебный проект - реализовывали приложение, составляющее блок-схему по введенному пользователем коду. С синxронизацией между кодом и cxемой, а пользователь мог редактировать и то, и другое.

А взаимодействие между классами - это совсем другое. Блок-схемы всё-таки нужны в случае процедурно-ориентированного кода. Или, в случае с ООП, для документирования отдельного алгоритма.

Comment: вопрос схохей тематики http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534011/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/534014#534014 Я пользуюсь программой FCEditor НЕ НОВАЯ ВЕРСИЯ!

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам блок схему распечатывать потом на A1, то рекомендую dia, хоть программа и неособо удобная, но линии там ровные получаются и не нужно выравнивать очень долго (чтобы не было "лесенок" или как это называется). Сам намулчася с выбором редактора для блок-схему и uml диаграмм. Если Вам просто нарисовать боок-схему, то можно и Visio.