# Программа для составления, редактирования алгоритов в графическом представлении

Tags: алгоритм, проектирование

Нужна программа для графического представления алгоритмов. Чтобы стрелки сама выставляла, и поддерживала конструкции яыков программирования for while foreach switch if и т д.

Во всем сети я нашел только одну единственную, но она глючная и не очень удобная.

Отредактированный скриншот для примера того как выглядит алгоритм в графическом виде. http://itmages.ru/image/view/4403812/73330364

---

Если это дубликат вопроса, то прошу меня простить.

Comment: или... нужно поступить как истинный хокэр: самому написать программулину? - ээх, жаль знаний не хватает :(

Comment: Вопрос задан понятно, [просто он оффтопик](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: На самом деле эта ниша сейчас открытая. Самое практичное, что я на сегодняшний день видел, это [Scratch](http://digitalgamesdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/SCRATCH1.png), но он больше для обучения, чем для промышленности. В промышленности подобные инструменты не приняты. Максимум UMLки с генерацией классов-заглушек, которые впоследствии алгоритмами заполнять.

Comment: я не стал писать название той программы, в которой сделан алгоритм. называется она FCEditor 1.6. Версия именно 1.6!!! Когда-то писал автору - он был согласен за пиво дописать, переписать  ее. И вот пару дней назад еще раз написал, указав ссылку на этот вопрос. В итоге ни проветаа, ни ответа. А может он пыхтит над  созданиием. И скоро появиться нечто... Или он умер? FCEditor - ЕДИНСТВЕННАЯ ПРОГРАММА В СВОЕМ РОДЕ.

Comment: Отношение к программированию это ещё не всё. Перечитайте страницу по ссылке и причину закрытия. В текущей редакции любой ответ правильный, неправильным его можете считать только вы сами. Вот субъективизм. Поэтому вопрос и закрыт.

Comment: уже читаю. нужно хоть когда-то правила глянуть ;:))

Answer (score 1):

Dia. Microsoft Visio. Остальное - грустно и не по ГОСТу.

Comment: dia - не годится! ms visio??? - ну незнаю,... чтобы пользователь linux использовал m$овые продуты. та и стрелки там автоматом не ставятся, наверное?

Comment: ото что я выше прирвел (скриншот) - то это при помощи FCEditor 1.6 (именно версия 1.6). Более новые не пригодны. Я даже связывался с автором чтобы он дописал, переписал программу, но сейчас у меня даже на еду денег нет. А платить ему копейки как-то не по людски будет. Я обязательно его отблагодарю, но для начала нужно дописать сайт и заработать денег.

Comment: visio есть и бесплатный http://visiofree.ru/ . стрелки там ставятся весьма удобно, привязаны к блокам, можно все вместе перетаскивать.

еще вот рекомендуют https://www.lucidchart.com/ , сама не пробовала.

Comment: lucid не оно. Вы просто не работали с FCEditor 1.6 Я только что написал автору еще раз.

Comment: :(( Все не то что надо.

Comment: кажется уже нашел. сейчас протестирую, посмотрю...

Comment: еще мне подсказали http://www.yworks.com/products/yed/download , но это не то что нужно